# How do I find a child by tag name of a variable element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How, in JavaScript, can I search for a child element from this code?

(Sorry, I'm not an expert with naming things or making my code look "neat and organized.")

```
var thisWin = document.querySelector("#tempWindow").cloneNode(true);
bodyOrDocument = (document.documentElement || document.body)
bodyOrDocument.appendChild(thisWin)
```

I am cloning an element, and the clone has no classes or IDs, so I tried this:

```
windowId = random(0, 10000000).toString();
thisWin.setAttribute("id", windowId)
thisWiniFrame = document.querySelector("#" + windowId + " iframe");
```

But I get this error in the console:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#8722143 iframe' is not a valid selector.`

I know the tag names are not reliable, but it's only for testing purposes anyways, so it's not really that important to me.

Anyways, does anybody know why is this error showing up? I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: My assumption would be it is angry at the number only id.

Comment: why you need the "iframe" part?

Comment: @Taplar Let me try that!

Comment: Yeah, a selector of `#a1234` is fine.  `#1234` is an error

Comment: @Berto99 I have an Iframe inside of the element with the ID and need to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id.):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

thus the error

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rL4mdx3q/  With the caveat that `getElementById` doesn't care.

Comment: This is the HTML4 spec. In HTML5 an ID can begin with a number, although CSS might throw a fit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @j08691 yep: https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#id-selectors -> https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier -> **In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit**